# Draw multi-line BitmapFont vertically centered

Tags: libgdx, text-rendering

I wish to center some long wrapped text that spans several lines on a rectangle (or anything else) like in the image below (I don't need to hide excess text but it'd be a big plus I'd be so grateful):

[image]

I've been able to achieve vertical centering with a single-line text like below:

```java
BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont();
String text = "Hello";
Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);

void render(SpriteBatch spriteBatch) {
    font.draw(
        spriteBatch,
        text,
        bounds.x,
        bounds.y + bounds.height / 2f + font.getLineHeight());
}
```

I know there's a `BitmapFont.draw()` method variant that lets you specify horizontal alignment, the target width of your text and a wrapping flag but I can't seem to find a way to **vertically** align multi-line text.

In the past this was possible with `BitmapFont.getBounds()` and some math but there's no such method in LibGDX 1.9.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [GlyphLayout](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/GlyphLayout.html) class we can get the height of your wrapped text, I've made a helper method to center the text inside a `Rectangle` improving the readability of code in the main `render()` method of our apps/games:

```java
private static GlyphLayout glyphLayout = new GlyphLayout();
public static void drawCentered(BitmapFont font, SpriteBatch spriteBatch,
                                    String text, Rectangle bounds) {
        glyphLayout.setText(font, text, Color.BLACK, bounds.width, Align.center, true);
        font.draw(
                spriteBatch,
                text,
                bounds.x,
                bounds.y + bounds.height / 2f + glyphLayout.height / 2f,
                bounds.width,
                Align.center,
                true);
    }
```